# Python requests to upload file on django server

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am trying to upload an image file to django server using python requests library. But the requests.FILES is empty.

Here is the django snippet:

```
elif request.method=='POST':
    print request.FILES
```

It gives:

```
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

Here is the python requests based script to upload the file:

```
headers['X-CSRFToken']=cookies['csrftoken']

params={}
params['title']="Sea of sand"

files={'file':('image.jpeg', open('image.jpeg', 'rb'))}
post=requests.post(url,headers=headers,cookies=cookies,params=params,files=files)
```

Please suggest what to do to get the snippet working. I have searched here and I have used the methods suggested but to no success.

Comment: Are there any other keys in `headers`?

Comment: @Martijn There are no other fields.

Comment: Then your `requests` code is correctly sending a `multipart/form-data` request to the server. Something on the Django side is wrong. You can validate what you post by changing the URL to `http://httpbin.org/post`; the service will echo back what you sent in a JSON response.